# why to use query_posts() in custom page?

Tags: query-posts

Hi i am new in wordpress and want to know about `query_posts()` function. If there is index page or home page than there is no need this function to display post but if i made custom page than there this function must used to display. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts)

For a custom post type or a simple page you don’t need `query_posts()`. Usually, you almost never need it, because it will replace the default query which leads to some counter-intuitive side effects.

When in doubt use [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts).

Answer (score 1):

i agree w/ get_posts() for a secondary loop.  if you need to modify the query on one of your templates i'd suggest using pre_get_posts()

http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Queries